# Умножить подходящие числа

Tags: c++, c

Написать программу, которая введет 5 значений и посчитает произведение чисел, которые делятся без остатка на 3 и не делятся без остатка на 5.

Я пытался сделать что то, но я трейни в плюсах и в си:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /*перша лабораторна*/
    int a, b, c, d, e;

    int res;
    int res = a * b * c * d * e;

    cout << "Enter 5 numbers:";
    cin >> a;
    cout << res;

if (a % 3 == 0 && b % 5 >= 1);
{

}



}
```

Comment: res положите равным 1. Куча переменных не нужна, используйте цикл для ввода, проверки и домножения.

Comment: ``b % 5 >= 1`` лучше заменить на ``b % 5 != 0``. Это более понятно и привычно. Ну и как бы по условиям надо сначала проверять делимость, а потом умножать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно сначала ввести 5 чисел, затем перебрать их, для каждого проверить требуемое условие, и если оно выполнено - добавить число в произведение.

Вот код с комментариями по шагам.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /*перша лабораторна*/
    int nums[5];  // Заводим массив на 5 чисел
    cout << "Enter 5 numbers:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        // В цикле поочередно вводим 5 чисел
        cin >> nums[i];
    }

    // Изначально переменная с произведением равна 1
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        // Если число "хорошее" - домножаем его к итоговому произведению
        // "Хорошее" - делится на 3 и не делится на 5, как написано в задаче
        if ( ( (nums[i] % 3) == 0) && ( (nums[i] % 5) != 0) )
        {
            res = res * nums[i];
        }
    }

    // Выводим результат
    cout << "Result is " << res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```